# aes 16byte size in md5

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to understand some code

```
The 32-byte AES encryption key and the 16-byte IV are both derived from   the password and the salt like so:
salted = password . salt     # . is the concatenation of the two
key1   = md5(salted)         # key1 is 16 bytes long
key2   = md5(key1 . salted)  # key2 is 16 bytes long
iv     = md5(key2 . salted)  # this is the 16-byte IV
aeskey = key1 . key2         # this is the 32-byte AES key
```

How is that md5(salted) can be 16 bytes? even though md5 is 32 bytes?

Comment: Where did you hear that MD5 is 32 bytes? Punch "MD5" into your favorite search engine and you will see that it produces a 128-bit hash, which is 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 has a 128-bit (16-byte) output, and always has. It's 32 characters when printed as hexadecimal, but that's because every *two* hex digits represent one byte.